# Faced error "==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer:", while implementing running sum of arrays problem using for_each loop. What can be the cause?

Tags: c++, foreach

I know the "running sum of arrays" problem is a easy problem which can be solved by for loop itself. But I was trying to implement using the for_each loop. And it is causing the error "==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer:" Runtime issue.

Can anyone help here?

Expectation:

Input : [2,5,6,7]

output : [2,7,13,20]

My code snippet:

```
vector<int> runningSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        int sum = 0;
        vector<int> resVector{};
        for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [&](int i){
            sum += nums[i];
            resVector.push_back(sum);
        });
        return resVector;
    }
```

Error :

```
> =================================================================
> ==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6020000000a0 at pc 0x0000003559ff bp 0x7ffcc2d3f350 sp 0x7ffcc2d3f348
> READ of size 4 at 0x6020000000a0 thread T0
> \#3 0x7f94526bc082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
> 0x6020000000a0 is located 0 bytes to the right of 16-byte region \[0x602000000090,0x6020000000a0)
> allocated by thread T0 here:
> \#6 0x7f94526bc082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
> Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
> 0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff8000: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
> =\>0x0c047fff8010: fa fa 00 00\[fa\]fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa 00 00
> 0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
> Addressable:           00
> Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
> Heap left redzone:       fa
> Freed heap region:       fd
> Stack left redzone:      f1
> Stack mid redzone:       f2
> Stack right redzone:     f3
> Stack after return:      f5
> Stack use after scope:   f8
> Global redzone:          f9
> Global init order:       f6
> Poisoned by user:        f7
> Container overflow:      fc
> Array cookie:            ac
> Intra object redzone:    bb
> ASan internal:           fe
> Left alloca redzone:     ca
> Right alloca redzone:    cb
> Shadow gap:              cc
> ==22==ABORTING
```

Comment: The lambda in for_each() actually accepts parameters for each element in the iterator, not their index.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is essentially adding up `nums[nums[i]]` for all `i` in the range `[0, nums.size())`. That's gonna fly off the end of the vector's allocated memory, given the values you're using as indices.

The way `for_each` works is it dereferences every iterator and passes the resulting value to the lambda. In other words, it passes the contents of the vector, not the index.

So, you just wanted `sum += i;`:

```
vector<int> runningSum(vector<int>& nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    vector<int> resVector{};
    for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [&](int i){
        sum += i;
        resVector.push_back(sum);
    });
    return resVector;
}
```

This issue is most probably a copy/paste or conversion error resulting from you converting your implementation from a standard loop to a `for_each`.

If you had used `nums.at(i)` here, this error would have been easier to track down because it would throw a [std::out_of_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception, and you'd get a breakpoint where you'd see `i` has an "unexpected" value.

---

Note that there is a standard library function [std::partial_sum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) that can perform the same operation:

```
std::vector<int> runningSum(const std::vector<int>& nums) {
    std::vector<int> result(nums);
    std::partial_sum(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}
```

Or even:

```
std::vector<int> runningSum(const std::vector<int>& nums) {
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(nums.size());
    std::partial_sum(nums.begin(), nums.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}
```